# Need help in finding these cable labels

Tags: networking, labeler

I was watching a video on [Cisco's new data center in Allen Texas](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=i4IrSARTUkY) and at the 7:15 mark they show some interesting cabel labels - photo attached.

Can anyone help identify where I can purchase these labels, and the printer necessary to print them?

[image: photo of labels]

Comment: They look like Panduit Marker plates, you can even get the in metal.

Comment: Thanks dbasnett! That is excatly what they are. Now the bad news -- they cost $425 for a roll of 500, and require a $1,500 printer from Panduit... Ouch!

Comment: What on earth would that long string of numbers and letters tell Amazon about that cable?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like these might be what you're looking for.

http://www.cablemarkers.com/tiptags.htm

Answer (score 1):

dbasnett correctly identified the labels.

They can be found here:

http://www.panduit.com/Products/ProductOverviews/ProductSearch/index.htm?N=5000001+1515+3004445&Ne=1&R=M200X042FPT